# Vertcoin-cli getinfo - gives me an error

Tags: bitcoin

I'm trying to check if my `vertcoind` is running and syncing. I get this

command:

```
vertcoin-cli getinfo
```

Response:

```
error code: -32601
error message:
Method not found
```

If I try to start `vertcoind` - just to check if it was closed.

```
./vertcoind -daemon

Error: Cannot obtain a lock on data directory /home/anelmann/.vertcoin. Vertcoin Core is probably already running.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getinfo` parameter isn't correct. Try:

```
vertcoin-cli -getinfo
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/785317)

Comment: Actually, @Yaron - the OP didn't pose a question therefore one must infer one. As the title refers to `getinfo` not producing an output this is as correct as you can get unless the OP does in fact clarify a question. Having had this issue directly others are likely to find this answer not only correct but useful.